# Помогите, пожалуйста, задать переменную в Postman через вкладку Tests

Tags: javascript, java, json, api, postman

```
{
    "id": "637278d9d8c85d02791b3db2",
    "name": "Fignya11144555",
    "desc": "This board was created by juniour",
    "descData": null,
    "closed": false,
    "dateClosed": null,
    "idOrganization": "636006dbdb02a103b2292c00",
    и так далее
```

Хочу добавить в переменную среды значение поля id. Пишу следующее:
var id = pm.response.json().id;
pm.globals.set("board_id", id);
результат Status: 200 OK. Но в переменных сохраняется не корректно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как решить проблему, подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: я вижу board_id в Globals. Есть pm.environment.set("board_id ", id);   Сайт https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-set-and-get-dynamic-environmental-variable/7482

Comment: pm.environment.set("board_id ", id); не работает